# Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Object Raphael already exists as a class, enum, or interface

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with the Navigation menu which does not show up to normal users. So, later today I saw this error when I debugged my page. This error shows on page load:

```
Uncaught Sys.InvalidOperationException: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Object Raphael already exists as a class, enum, or interface.
```

Apparently this error is thrown in ScriptResource.axd.

I am not sure where it is getting this name "Raphael". There is a custom solution deployed, but there is no such name in it.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Update:
I created a new web application and a site collection, of course, so I tested it there but I don't get the same error. I am getting some other errors though but not that one. `Automation server can't create object`

[image]

Comment: Is the custom solution loading a control twice on the page at all? Are you able to reproduce on a new site collection?

Comment: I don't see any duplicate controls on the page. Unless there is something hidden. I will try to create an empty site collection and test it there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my post above, please have a look.

Comment: Might be worth asking with the vendor of the custom solution? Doesn't look like anything SharePoint normally throws up.

Comment: Looks to me like a javascript Raphael namespace (or scope) is being loaded/reserved twice. Did a search on Raphael, it seems to be a js library (I've never heard of it). http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html. It's has something to do with vectors/images apparently.

Comment: I search the solution for a reference to Raphael, but there is none. Not directly. I found that "Raphael" is used in the "vizit-all.js" which is found in 15 hive in sharepoint.